# Does Flask's url_for have a string limit for query strings?

Tags: flask

Does Flask's `url_for` have a string limit for query strings?

```
url_for('verify', t='e5e781eef6f1fa9d9062c7831ae7ec5bed3b67ac', _external=True)
```

This returns:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/verify?t=e5e781eef6f1fa9d9062c783
```

The original string is 40 characters, the generated query string is 24 characters.

What's going on?

Comment: How you define your view because for example `app.add_url_rule('/<t>', 'verify', lambda t: 'hello')` and `app.add_url_rule('/', 'verify', lambda: 'hello')` return right value for me? Did you have `app.url_defaults` or any other manipulations with `app.url_default_functions`?

Comment: It seems really weird to me that you're having GET parameters as part of the route. I'd try using something like ``/verify/<t>``.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this behaviour from scratch

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    print url_for('hello', t='e5e781eef6f1fa9d9062c7831ae7ec5bed3b67ac', _external=True)
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

>>>  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
>>>  http://127.0.0.1:5000/?t=e5e781eef6f1fa9d9062c7831ae7ec5bed3b67ac
```

It returns the right url. There maybe a problem in your Jinja template output.